# How should I specify AOP aspect for overloaded methods?

Tags: java, spring, aop, overloading

I develop application in Java and Spring AOP. Anything is good, but I've created overloaded method and want to set up AOP.

Simple duplication with changing `aop:pointcut` id doesn't help.

Comment: Can you post some source (Spring config relevant part and the methods) and explain what "doesn't help" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try it out myself, but there is also a pointcut for matching on arguments:

Something like:

```
@Pointcut("args(java.io.Serializable, your.package.YourClass)")
public void pointcutArgs() {
}
```

See:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/aop.html